# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache2

Antes que nada comento que previamente a esto, tenía otro error que fue solucionado (mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost') al actualizar los permisos de root@localhost y el plugin de la tabla 'user'.

Ahora se me presenta este nuevo error al intentar iniciar sesión en phpMyAdmin. Toda la configuración de mysql, apache y php la realice mediante la consola de comandos, así que no utilicé ningún instalador cómo XAMP o Bitnami.

Soy bastante nuevo con todo lo que es PHP, MySql y bases de datos, así que si pueden recomendarme alguna guía que me oriente un poco sería genial.

Muchas gracias!

Alguno sabe que puedo hacer? Lo más probable es que me haya salteado algún paso a la hora de configurar MySql-server, aunque me parecería raro porque lo estuve usando varios meses para hacer las practicas de Bases de Datos en la facultad.

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: está denegando el acceso al usuario `root`. Debes indicar la contraseña correcta o mandarle una cadena vacía como contraseña según el caso (en muchos escenarios `root` viene sin contraseña por defecto). Muestra sobre qué código arroja el error, puedes [edit] la pregunta para ello. Gracias.